# Button unpresses itself (possibly device specific)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-hardware

I'm trying to troubleshoot a tricky, difficult to reproduce (therefore possibly hardware related) problem for the [open source Panic Button application](https://github.com/iilab/PanicButton) I'm working on for Amnesty. There's [an issue on github about it](https://github.com/iilab/PanicButton/issues/63).

The issue is with a [LinearLayout View with Buttons](https://github.com/iilab/PanicButton/blob/dev/res/layout/calculator_layout.xml). When displayed in [this fragment](https://github.com/iilab/PanicButton/blob/dev/src/main/java/org/iilab/pb/fragment/WizardAlarmTestDisguiseFragment.java#L50), when I try to hold a button, it just unpresses itself after one second exactly. When logging the onClick event, it triggers itself automatically even though I haven't released my finger from the screen.

This happens on the Cherry Gem phone, and I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on other phones.

I've been removing a lot of code and adding lots of logging statements to try and isolate the bug when I discovered the strangest thing, which led me to post this on Stack Overflow since it's strange enough that maybe someone will recognise the pattern:

**When I drag my finger on the screen, then the bug goes away!** More precisely, after confirming on the screen that the button unpresses itself a few times, if I hold and drag my finger around, then release it, after that I can hold buttons pressed without them unpressing themselves. **Wat?**

Please note that I'm not asking to solve the problem of trying to detect a long press (which this leads to of course), but trying to understand this problem of unwanted unpressing before I move on to implement a workaround. Therefore I'd also would prefer not to move the events to onTouch listeners, because I'm worried it would not address the root cause of the problem and I'd like to understand why this is happening first.

I'm not a 100% sure if there could be an unwanted interaction with the rest of the code and will also try to create a minimalistic project from scratch with only that code, if no-one recognises the pattern here.

I can also post a small video of the problem if that helps.  I'm also happy to post code excerpts or logcat results.

Thanks for your time!

Jun

## Update

I've looked at [the adb shell getevent log](https://github.com/iilab/PanicButton/issues/63#issuecomment-88397065) which confirms that after .9 seconds there is an `EV_KEY BTN_TOUCH UP` 
event. Does this confirm that from the OS's standpoint, it's receiving an event from the hardware about a button up? I guess this might be also triggered by software.

This led me to look into software that is installed on the phone and could interfere with the input devices. I've deactivated the Google voice typing, and then holding buttons worked again. Reactivating Google voice typing didn't make the bug reappear. Rebooting the phone then makes the bug reappear.

I tried to look at whether only some applications were affected. The pre-installed calculator was also affected. When using the default virtual keyboard the bug didn't happen. But then when returning to my app the bug had gone away again. Rebooted again. Calculator still affected. Go back to using the virtual keyboard in the browser. Now the bug stays... Wat?

After a while, I removed the Google voice typing input device again and the bug disappeared once more.

I have tracked a forum where there seems to be a rom for this phone, I'm trying to find out whether it's more recent than the version I have, or if anyone else with this phone experienced that problem as well.

(I also updated the [relevant github issue](https://github.com/iilab/PanicButton/issues/63))

## Update 2

I noticed the following in the logcat:

```
04-01 12:05:30.484: V/PhoneWindow(2749): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0
04-01 12:05:30.525: V/InputMethodManager(2749): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#1810100
04-01 12:05:30.528: V/InputMethodManager(2749): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41aa5ef8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-480,800} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41a3fef8 controlFlags=#104
04-01 12:05:30.530: V/InputMethodManager(2749): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@41a48da8 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #45}
04-01 12:05:30.608: I/InputMethodManager(2749): handleMessage: MSG_SET_ACTIVE true, was false
```

Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: The phone might have a bad touchscreen, which is common with cheap Chinese phones, and the touchscreen could be registering the touch on it's own because of that. Try / create a different app, put a button in the same place on-screen, and see if it still happens.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I'm afraid it's probably not the cause. Other buttons on other screens or apps can long press just fine. It's just this particular view that does this.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know why this happens, but if you want, I can put a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on your question, which will get it more visibility, and (hopefully) an answer. Just tell me so in two days (the required time to wait), and I can do it.

Comment: That's very nice of you to offer! I'll ping you if there's no answer by then. Cheers.

Comment: Hi Jonas, looks like the question didn't get much attention... can I take you on your offer?

Comment: I wonder if you could be running into a filtering or even dynamic recalibration behavior deep in the touchscreen implementation - ie, there may be an assumption that no legitimate touch event is that long.  It would be easy to imagine the change in behavior you see when moving your finger around being related to this.

Comment: Yep! I know it's not really practical here, but an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) usually helps a lot.  Also, if the bug is device-specific, it is very hard to debug without actually having the device. You should try the Eclipse / Android Studio debugger, and see if that tells you anything. Also try ADB shell getevent, as suggested below.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, OP says that other screens or apps do not exhibit this problem, so that kind of rules out the touchscreen.

Comment: You might want to try running adb shell getevent or similar both for your button and others and seeing what the events look like at that level, on this device vs on others.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisStratton I have tried adb shell getevent and posted [the results here](https://github.com/iilab/PanicButton/issues/63). I also added more information in my original post and things are still as strange as ever.  I wish I had a MCVE. I'm trying to narrow it down as much as I can. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Aha! If it's Google Voice Typing that's causing this, it is _very_ likely that this is a bug in the device's android implementation or a bug in GVT, not in your app. You might be able to find out if there is a way / workaround to prevent GVT from sending input into your app.

Answer (score 1):

For odd problems such as this, I think it's useful to override the **onTouchEvent** listener, and observe which **MotionEvent** is triggered (like ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP/DOWN). The root problem may be the touch screen driver of the device. So it may be good to test that driver with onTouchEvent.

There is, I think, a good webpage @ [Touch Device Configuration](https://source.android.com/devices/input/touch-devices.html#touch-device-configuration). Search text for "Driver reports signal strength as pressure". I think this is interesting and perhaps you could simply change the values for touch.pressure.**calibration** or/and **scale** for troubleshooting. This file has extension of idc, should reside on system subdirectory.

I want to provide sample code to override mouse/swiping events:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            // Make sure ACTION_DOWN is dispatched to children view
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                onTouchEvent(ev);

                // Allow the children view to process this action
                return false;       // skip calling onInterceptTouchEvent

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                onTouchEvent(ev);
                return false;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mDownX = (int)event.getX();
                mDownY = (int)event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
...
```

Notes:

- Method onInterceptTouchEvent occurs before onTouchEvent.
- This method intercepts all touch screen motion events. This allows you to watch events as they are dispatched to your children.

Comment: Thanks! I've [tried adb shell getevent](https://github.com/iilab/PanicButton/issues/63#issuecomment-88397065), which I think is in the same spirit as your recommendation and updated my post with further testing results. I think the problem is not with the normal operation of the hardware itself or with the driver, but with something that interferes with it. Maybe another service that can hook into the input device, or maybe something with the firmware that's not right... Do you think that's possible?

Comment: It's hard for me to believe that a service will send click messages to the device or onto an app like yours. I read your log results and Google Voice seems to be the culprit of this issue. But it's hard to remove that app considering you don't have direct control over another (perhaps popular) app. So it's not a good solution. Maybe it's easier if the solution is to simply update the Android version.

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty even though your answer is not quite the best, as I hate to see the bounty rep just disappear. Maybe you could improve / expand your answer a little ?

Comment: I finally added more comments in an attempt to be more helpful.